# SonarScanner Error during SonarScanner execution

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I created a sonarplugin when I am using that plugin in Sonarqube and when I  am running a sonar scan using Jenkins Sonar Scanner plugin, getting below error. Without plugin it is working fine
I am using Java 11 , Sonar Scanner version 4.6.

```
08:14:20.829 ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader.loadClass(IsolatedClassloader.java:82)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:84)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:76)
    at org.sonar.classloader.DefaultClassloaderRef.loadClassIfPresent(DefaultClassloaderRef.java:40)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClassFromParent(ClassRealm.java:147)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ParentFirstStrategy.loadClass(ParentFirstStrategy.java:35)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:87)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:76)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:125)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ParentFirstStrategy.loadClass(ParentFirstStrategy.java:37)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:87)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:76)
    at com.sonarqube.plugin.JwtAuthPlugin.define(JwtAuthPlugin.java:28)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ExtensionInstaller.install(ExtensionInstaller.java:60)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.addScannerExtensions(ProjectScanContainer.java:320)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:154)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:150)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:72)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:66)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader.loadClass(IsolatedClassloader.java:82)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 52 more
```

My javax dependency:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```